# Retrofit API call returns empty object

Tags: android, rest, retrofit, retrofit2

Here are my classes, I am using to make rest api call.
Product, Products, an end point ZappoAPI. A method callRestAPI is called from controller where rest api is called asynchronously. I am getting empty list in response.

```
public class Product {
    private String productId;

    public Product(String productId) {
        this.productId = productId;
    }


    public String getBrandName() {
        return productId;
    }

    public void setBrandName(String productId) {
        this.productId = productId;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return(productId);
    }
}



public class Products {
    List<Product> products  = new ArrayList<>();
    public List<Product> getProducts() {
        return products;
    }
}



public interface ZappoAPI {
    @GET("/Search")
    Call<ZappoProducts> searchProducts(@Query("term") String tags, @Query("key") String key);

}
```

public void callRestAPI(){

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl("https://api.zappos.com")
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .build();




// prepare call in Retrofit 2.0
ZappoAPI zappoAPI = retrofit.create(ZappoAPI.class);

Call<ZappoProducts> call = zappoAPI.searchProducts(this.prodName, IConstant.API_KEY);
//asynchronous call
call.enqueue(this);

String url = call.request().url().toString();

Log.d("url is",url);
Log.d("url is",url);
```

}

```
on callback method -

public void onResponse(Call<ZappoProducts> call, Response<ZappoProducts> response) {

        boolean isSuccess = response.raw().isSuccessful();
        List<Product> products = new ArrayList<>();

        if(isSuccess){
            products = response.body().getProducts();
        }


        String[] values = new String[products.size()];


        for (int i=0;i<products.size();i++){
            values[i] = products.get(i).toString();
        }

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = (ArrayAdapter<String>) this.adapter;
        adapter.clear();
        adapter.addAll(values);



    }
```

Now, onresponse, I am getting empty products list.
Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: have you tried to get result in Postman?

Comment: What is ``ZappoProducts`` ?

Comment: Can you provide the JSON received?